Passing component as function to affect the state of upper-level components?
I'm reading the book Advanced React: Deep dives, investigations, performance patterns and techniques. In the first chapter, which is an introduction to re-renders, I'm struggling to understand the following text:

The only way for components at the "bottom" to affect components at the "top" of the hierarchy is for them either to explicitly call state update in the "top" components or to pass components as functions.

I understand the first part. An example would be the descendant component calling the set function returned by a useState hook call from the upper-level component.
What about the second part, which is about passing components as functions? How is this supposed to affect the state?

In React, passing components as functions refers to the concept of passing callback functions from higher-level components to lower-level components. These callback functions can then be invoked by the lower-level components to trigger state updates or other actions in the higher-level components.
I hope this example will make you understand of passing components as functions:
// Higher-level component
function ParentComponent() {
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

 const incrementCount = () => {
   setCount(count + 1);
 };

 return <ChildComponent increment={incrementCount} />;
 }

 // Lower-level component
 function ChildComponent({ increment }) {
   return <button onClick={increment}>Increment Count</button>;
 }

By invoking the callback function in the lower-level component, it triggers the execution of the function defined in the higher-level component. This function typically updates the state in the higher-level component.
Once the state is updated in the higher-level component, React re-renders the affected components, including both the higher-level component and its descendants.

So, is it the same as stated in the first part of the text but calling the set function indirectly?

I don't believe what you have provided is an example of passing a component as props.   I think an example of that would be render props or Higher Order Components. What you have provided is explicitly call state update in the "top"  components
